how to handle exceptions in SparkJava
I'm trying to handle all exception (exception handler) for SparkJava
I am currently using try/catch blocks in each endpoint but that approach doesn't scale properly.
Something that can handle different kind of exception for return types, like 4xx or 5xx
Any alternatives like Spring/Play?

when using
        post("/account", (request, response) -> {
            Account account = new Gson().fromJson(request.body(), Account.class);
            accountService.add(account);
            response.status(204);
            return response;
        });

you can add this,
        exception(RuntimeException.class, (e, request, response) -> {
            response.status(400);
            response.body(e.getMessage());
        });


